# Too few arguments to function when calling another method of a same Class

Tags: php, laravel, class, oop, php-8

I'm working with PHP and I have made this Class:

```
class Captcha
{
    public function make()
    {
          $phrase = strtoupper(bin2hex(random_bytes(3)));
            
          $this->check($phrase);
    }

    public function check($phrase)
    {
          return $phrase;
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

### **Too few arguments to function **

So what's going wrong here?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

Here is how I call the method at the other Controller class:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('get'))
        {
            $phrase = app('App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha')->check();
            dd($phrase);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole error ?

Comment: how are u calling the methods? where are u getting the error? here u r only showing us the class declaration

Comment: Which function is the error referring to?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error [here](https://3v4l.org/lFotF)

Comment: idk what u want to do exactly since u dont provide any useful info to the helper, but maybe change `$this->check($phrase);` to `return $this->check($phrase);`

Comment: @xenooooo `Too few arguments to function App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha::check(), 0 passed in AuthController.php on line 20 and exactly 1 expected`

Comment: @ericmp I call it on another Controller method like this: `$phrase = app('App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha')->check();`

Comment: Well you didn't pass an argument

Comment: You need to add an argument `$phrase = app('App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha')->check('value')`

Comment: @xenooooo But I don't want the `value` as parameter. The `make` method itself makes the **`$phrase`** and I just need to get it at the other Controller method

Comment: you need to declare a default value to the `App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha::check()` something like `public function check($phrase = null)` so you can use it without adding a `value` but it will return a null

Comment: @xenooooo Then it returns `null`. However the `$phrase` is already created!

Comment: Can you show how you use the function.

Comment: @xenooooo Okay I'm going to update the question right now

Comment: @xenooooo I just updated the question. Please see **UPDATE #1**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249577/discussion-between-yetep93258-and-xenooooo).

Comment: Based on your update you are calling `check` which requires 1 parameter but your are not passing anything. Not sure how you wanted this to work but my guess is you want to do what @ericmp suggested initially and `return $this->check($phrase);` and then call `$phrase = app('App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha')->make();`. Still I am only guessing at this point it's not clear what the purpose of this code actually is

Answer (score 0):

Change

```php
$phrase = app('App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha')->check();
```

to

```php
$phrase = app('App\Http\HelperClasses\Captcha')->check('value');
```